# change image display into inline

Tags: html, css

i am making a image slider .i am trying to display images inline .i have apllied css also but it is not working :(  image are not displayed inline. what property need to be change please help.

```
<div id="f1_container">
    <div id="f1_card1" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="thumb1.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            Some text inside here
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div id="f1_card2" class="shadow">
        <div class="front face">
            <img src="thumb2.jpg" style="height: 281px; width: 450px;" />
        </div>
        <div class="back face center">
            text2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is my CSS file,

```
 #f1_container {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 450px;
    height: 281px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#f1_container {
    -webkit-perspective: 1000;
    perspective: 1000;
}
#f1_card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s linear;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 1.0s linear;
}
#f1_container:hover #f1_card {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #aaa;
}
.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.back {
    display: block;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: try to give the Image a display:inline and a float:left

Comment: Images are by default inline-level elements. However, in your case the images are nested inside `div` elements, which are by default block-level elements. So your efforts should be aimed at making the `div` containers to be inline-level elements, and not the images.

Comment: did you try span ? btw it looks fine..can't say what's the problem

Comment: which browser you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by increasing body width in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You mite want to put the image and text inside a div and float the div's so there in line with float:left;

Answer (score 0):

define style for shadow ..  position:relative & float:left
also remove  br elements between divs with class shadow